# How to multiply $2 \sin(x) \cdot \sin^{2} (x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am just confused on the way you would multiply this out, if you could help that would be fantastic. The pre calc method for doing these is the solution I am looking for

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Hint: What does the notation $\sin^2(x)$ actually mean?

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics, it is very common to write $\sin^2(x)$ to represent $[\sin(x)]^2$.

Therefore, rewriting your question, you want to know the value of

$$2\sin(x)\sin^2(x)=2\sin(x)[\sin(x)]^2=2[\sin(x)]^3=2\sin^3(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The formula is: $y^m\cdot y^n = y^{m+n}$, use this for $y = \sin x, m = 1, n = 2$ in your problem.

Comment: That's good to know. So $\sin^{5} \cdot \sin^{-1} = \sin^{4}$?

Comment: Yes, it should be....

Comment: ODETutor well, that's not the case. $\sin^{-1}$ refers to the inverse of $\sin$, vs $\sin^2$ refers to the square of sin, which are uncorrelated functions

Answer (score 0):

First focus on your sin(x). When multiplying, $sin^n(x) * sin^m(x)$ = $sin^{n+m}(x)$. Therefore, $sin^1(x) * sin^2(x)$ = $sin^3(x)$. Then multiply by 2 to get $2sin^3(x)$.